# Como mudar objetos Graphics2d fora paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, java2d

Gostaria de saber como mudar a cor de um `drawRectangle()` de `Graphics2d` do java, fora do metodo `@Override paintComponent()`.

Acontece que essa mudança deve ser temporária, apenas quando o ponteiro do mouse passar sobre a área desenhada e quando sair dessa área, deve voltar a cor padrão do desenho. No algoritmo que usei, não consigo mudar a cor do retângulo da forma que descrevi. Se desejarem tentem recompilar o meu código, talvez seja mais fácil entender o problema.

```
package desenhoteste;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class DesenhoTeste extends JFrame {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    protected int xi;
    protected int xf;
    protected int yi;
    protected int yf;
    public Graphics2D g1;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DesenhoTeste frame = new DesenhoTeste();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public DesenhoTeste() {
        setTitle("Desenho Teste");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel areaDeEdicao = new AlteraGrafico();
        contentPane.add(areaDeEdicao, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        areaDeEdicao.setLayout(null);

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
            // MouseMotionListener
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                // Essas coordenadas, que são as mesmas do metodo drawRectangle, servem para simular uma área sensível em areaDeEdicao
                xi = 150;
                xf = 250;
                yi = 150;
                yf = 250;
                // Esse teste verifica se os valores de x e y, captados do mouse, estão dentro das coordenadas do retângulo, ou seja,
                // se e.getX() E e.getY() estão entre xi e xy; que equivale a: xi <= e.getX() <= xf ao mesmo tempo que yi <= e.getY() <= yf.
                while ((xi <= e.getX() && e.getX() <= xf) && (yi <= e.getY() && e.getY() <= yf)) {
                    // Uma tentativa de mudar o valor do campo g1 fora do metodo override paintComponent.
                    g1.setColor(Color.RED);
                    areaDeEdicao.repaint();
                    // System.out.println verifica se o while está funcionando, monitorando os valores de e.getX() E e.getY().
                    System.out.println("Mouse passou dentro do retângulo: " + "e.getXd(): " + e.getX() + " " + "e.getY(): " + e.getY());
                    break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            }
        });
    }

    public class AlteraGrafico extends JPanel {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        // Override gerado pelo atalho ctrl + space e clicando em paintComponent 
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g1 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g1.drawRect(150, 150, 100, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acontece que o método `paintComponent` é o responsável por renderizar o componente na tela, você tem que deixar a parte da lógica de desenho sempre dentro deste método.

O que fiz foi delegar o *listener* de movimento do mouse ao `JPanel`, já que o desenho encontra-se nele, e quando o mouse mover-se dentro deste painel, eu capturo as coordenadas atuais do ponteiro.

O método `paintComponent` é chamado constantemente dentro da Thread do swing, então joguei a validação de posição do mouse para dentro dele, e sempre que o mouse se mover dentro das coordenadas que o `if` valida, o retângulo terá sua cor de fundo alterada para vermelho por causa do `repaint()` dentro do método `mouseMoved`, e quando o mouse sair dessas coordenadas, volta a cor normal, pois a área será redesenhada com valores padrões e não entrará neste if.

Veja o código atualizado:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class DesenhoTeste extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DesenhoTeste frame = new DesenhoTeste();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public DesenhoTeste() {
        setTitle("Desenho Teste");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel areaDeEdicao = new AlteraGrafico();
        contentPane.add(areaDeEdicao, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        areaDeEdicao.setLayout(null);
    }

    public class AlteraGrafico extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {

        protected int xi;
        protected int xf;
        protected int yi;
        protected int yf;
        //estas variaveis guardam as coordenadas atuais quando o 
        // mouse mover por sobre este componente
        private int mX, mY;
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public AlteraGrafico() {
            xi = 150;
            xf = 250;
            yi = 150;
            yf = 250;
            addMouseMotionListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g1 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g1.drawRect(150, 150, 100, 100);

            if ((xi <= mX && mX <= xf) && (yi <= mY && mY <= yf)) {
                g1.setColor(Color.red);
                g1.fillRect(150, 150, 100, 100);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

            mX = e.getX();
            mY = e.getY();
           repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: diegofm, obrigado pela sua ajuda!

Comment: @Phrank funcionou? Se sim, você pode aceitar a resposta, clicando no `v` a esquerda. Assim ela servirá de exemplo para outras pessoas com problema semelhante :)